# How to properly screenshot an android device?

Tags: java, android

The image that I get has a segment from the middle of the phone as an artifact on the right.

**Android Code**

I use `MediaProjection` and `ImageReader`.

```
//OnCreate
display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
display.getSize(displaySize);
display.getMetrics(displayMetrics);
imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(displaySize.x, displaySize.y, 
    PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);

//onActivityResult
mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("screen", displaySize.x, displaySize.y, 
    displayMetrics.densityDpi, DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, 
    imageReader.getSurface(), null, null);

//ScheduledThread
Image image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
if(image != null) {
    final Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
    int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
    int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
    int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * image.getWidth();

    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth() + rowPadding / 
        pixelStride, image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

    byte[] byteArray;
    if(bitmap != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        socket.emit("frame", encoded);
    }
    image.close();
}
```

**Java Code**

```
socket.on("frame", args1 -> {
    byte[] bytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode((String)args1[0]);
    ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(bin);
        int type = img.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : img.getType();
        img = resizeImage(img, type);
        if(!frameOpen){
            openFrame(img.getWidth());
        }
        panel.removeAll();
        panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
        frame.pack();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
});


private static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int type) {
    double ratio = 1.0 * originalImage.getWidth() / originalImage.getHeight();
    int imgHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height - 100;
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage((int) ((int)imgHeight*ratio), imgHeight, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, (int) ((int)imgHeight*ratio), imgHeight, null);
    g.dispose();
    return resizedImage;
}
```

**Result**

As you can see in the image, on the far right, that thin line is from the middle portion of the image.
[image: Transmitted Screenshot]

What do you think is causing this?

**EDIT:** I know for a fact it's an error in the android code. Could my `ImageReader` or `createVirtualDisplay` be set up wrong?

I was able to get rid of the black bars by using:

> `display.getRealSize(displaySize);`

But that line segment is still there:
[image]

**Repo**

https://github.com/Decapitated/Android-Viewer

Comment: Did not quite understand the problem. The screenshot looks perfect!

Comment: Correct! But see on the right, it's hard to tell in this image, but that thin line is from the center of the image. That is my problem.

Comment: Oh dear God! Finally I get it. Phew! You should have marked this one by editing the image a little bit. :P

Comment: I agree. But people will read the comments at least.

Comment: Difficult to understand from the comments as well. You might consider editing to clarify.

Comment: You should also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56176279/edit) your post with the make and model of phone. i would also mention if you are using any specific home screen app.